# Can I Access one document's data from another document in mfc

Tags: c++, mfc, document

Im trying to make new doc type in mfc that reads data from another document type when needed. And my question is- Is this possible and how it should be done ?

Comment: Yes it's possible, you just have to write the code, start with an MDI application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CWinApp::GetFirstDocTemplatePosition()` and `CWinApp::GetNextDocTemplate()` to iterate through the doc templates.

Then, for each doc template, use `CDocTemplate::GetFirstDocPosition()` and `CDocTemplate::GetNextDoc()` to iterate through the documents.

You will need to make the document data public or provide getters/setters.